# show an user's posts in a specific page - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm writing a rails app and I want to show users' posts in separate pages like `/users/20/posts` .
I added both of these codes to routs.rb :

```
resources  :users do
 resources :posts, only: [:index]
end
```

and

```
get 'users/:id/posts' => 'users#posts', :as => :user_posts
```

but url like `/users/20/posts` shows all posts, not just this specific user's posts. (It behave as same as `/posts`)

I have these in my models and controllers (if needed):

user.rb :

```
has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
```

post.rb :

```
belongs_to :user
```

users_controller.rb :

```
def posts
 @user = User.find(params[:id])
 @posts = @user.posts
end
```

Comment: Typically the rails way would be to have a `posts_controller.rb`, where you can have an `index` method there. Why did you decide not to implement it this way?

Comment: I can show posts' index, but I want to show a specific user's posts. The `index` method inside `posts_controller` show all posts, not just a specific user's @AnthonyTo

Comment: do u have user_id in posts table ? do u assign user_id there ?

Comment: also you have syntax issue in `posts` method supposed to be closing parenthesis `@user = User.find(params[:user_id])`

Comment: I closed parenthesis. Yes I have `t.integer  "user_id"` in posts table @7urkm3n

Comment: did u notice that supposed tobe `params[:user_id]` for `User.find`

Comment: `:user_id` instead of `:id` doesn't work too @7urkm3n

Comment: commend out this line in rountes `resources :posts, only: [:index]` probably it overwrites. your custom `get` method.

Comment: @Saeed Check my post, below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test it just using Browser URL. It should work.

In **routes.rb**

```
resources  :users do
 resources :posts, only: [:index]
end

get 'users/:id/user_posts' => 'users#user_posts', :as => :custom_user_posts
```

In **users_controller.rb**

```
def user_posts
 @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
 @posts = @user.posts

 #render plain: {posts: @posts.inspect, user: @user.inspect} 
end
```

Now add a new file in view/users/**user_posts.html.erb**

In the page:

```
<% @posts.each do |p|%>
   loop right here your data
<% end %>
```

Comment: It show a white page whit this text: `#<Post::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007f082f5f8c80>` in browser

Comment: How can I realize that?

Comment: `rake db:migrate` and restart your server. also u said you have `user_id` in posts table. I hope you do. When creating new Post, assign user_id too.

Comment: I did both. It show that white page and that text yet.

Comment: Which texts do you mean?

Comment: I see just a white page whit this text: `#<Post::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007fc03d15d600>`

Comment: What data do you currently have ? Maybe all posts are stored with the same user_id ? Can you look into the DB and make sure the problem is not here ?

Comment: @babgyy No, I'm sure. I can see which user has posted every post.

Comment: @Saeed Can u goto `rails console`  and do like this `u = User.first` then `u.posts`. What kind of data u getting back empty array `[]` or `posts` ?

Comment: `Started GET "/users/18/user_posts" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-04-04 12:59:20 +0430
Processing by UsersController#user_posts as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"18"}
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 18]]
  Rendered text template (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 2ms (Views: 0.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.1ms)`
@7urkm3n

Comment: @Saeed I see everything loads perfectly. try again this one `localhost:3000/users/18/user_posts`, u should get white page with some JSON data .

Comment: In console, I get posts' data

Comment: check it in the browser too. i wanna know do u get that data to browser. let me know.

Comment: @Saeed Just updated the last post copy that one. Now u should see, i hope.

Comment: Yes! Now I see posts in text format. What I should do to display that posts in proper style?

Comment: @Saeed Update The Post.

Comment: What should I use instead of `loop right here your data` to display that specific users posts?

Comment: whats your post table columns ? if u have title use as like this. `<% @posts.each do |p|%>
 <%= p.title %>
<% end %>`

Comment: I will do, as soon as I get permission ;-)

Answer (score 0):

To do it your way , you need to change your routes to

```
resources  :users do
 get :posts
end
```

Comment: I don't think they even need to do that, since they are manually matching with this anyways: `get 'users/:id/posts' => 'users#posts', :as => :user_posts`

Comment: he said he added both routes, we don't know which one is the first one

Comment: I get this error `app/controllers/users_controller.rb:59: syntax error, unexpected tIVAR, expecting ')' @posts = @user.posts ^`

Comment: you are missing closing parenthesis in your `User.find` method

Comment: `@user = User.find(params[:id]` you need to close the bracket `User.find(params[:id])`

Comment: I closed the parenthesis. Now this error displays `Couldn't find User with 'id'=` @RajarshiDas @AnthonyTo

Comment: do you have users data on the table users?

Comment: I didn't get what you mean @RajarshiDas

Answer (score 0):

In your `index` action, add this

```
def index
  user = User.find_by_id(params[:user_id])
  @posts = user.posts 
end
```

Then display `@posts` in your views.